# In Angular, how to remove the selector tag from around the component's template?

Tags: angular, templates, components, selector

In Angular, how to remove the selector tag from around the component's template? It is making problems for
browser to display the `<td>` fields within the component. I have many instances of `<tr>` and each one has the first `<td>` styled differently:

```
<tr>
  <td>1.1</td><td>1.2</td>
        <app-summary-data-row [data]="data[1]">
        </app-summary-data-row>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td colspan=2>2</td>
            <app-summary-data-row [data]="data[2]">
            </app-summary-data-row>
        </tr>
```

But, the majority set of `<td>` follows the same pattern, so I want to make the into the same template. The trouble is the angular's tags, that distort the construct of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector instead in `@component` decorator:-

```
@Component({
  selector: '[component-name]'
  ...
})
```

And then use it as:-

```
<div component-name>
  ...
</div>
```

As per the documentation:-

> You can Specify a CSS selector that identifies this directive within a template. Supported selectors include element, [attribute], .class, and :not().
>
> Does not support parent-child relationship selectors.

Comment: thanks, but the thing is that I don't have the div, just a set of <td>-s stacked together.

Comment: Then you can use it on the `td` also..!

Comment: I updated the question. See that the problem makes the first of the <td>-s in a row, because all of them are different and/or even differently styled, so can't be put also in the template.

Comment: You can not do like it? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WBPajV?editors=1000